# Rendering axios state data fails and works sometimes

Tags: reactjs, axios, next.js

Im using axios to fetch data from an API with this code

```
const [coinData, setCoinData] = useState([]);
const [marketData, setMarketData] = useState([]);
const coin = router.query.handle;

useEffect(() => {
// coin data
axios.get("https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids="+coin+"&vs_currencies ... ")
.then(res => setCoinData(res.data))
.catch(err => console.log(err));

// marketdata
axios.get("https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/"+coin+"/mark ...")
.then(res => setMarketData(res.data))
.catch(err => console.log(err));
}, []);
```

and the way I'm rendering in the UI is just like this:

```
{coinData[coin].usd.toLocaleString('en-US', {maximumFractionDigits:2})}
```

but the problem is, sometimes it works, and sometimes it doesn't. Am I doing something wrong? I am also fairly new to react/netxjs, and if someone can tell me if im doing things wrong, it would be great. :)

Comment: Do the network calls always get made to the correct url?  It looks like coin should be a useEffect dependency.

Comment: Sometimes I can see in the logs that the calls aren't called yet. Is that the reason why? @jprosevear

Comment: Possible - ideally you would add eslint-plugin-react-hooks to make sure you have the deps set correctly.  Add useEffect(...,  [coin]) as a starting point.